# How to include JWT token in page navigation in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I am trying out JWT in ASP.NET Core but I am stumped on how to use it in page navigation. I have several controllers marked with Authorize attribute and I need to include the JWT in the header of the request to be able to access them.

I already am generating the token, I just don't know how I would include the token in the request header when navigating to a page marked with Authorize.

My questions are:

1. How do I add the token to the request so I can access the pages with Authorize upon navigation?
2. Are JWT tokens typically used in this fashion (page navigation), or mainly for API calls? Is it wrong to use it like this?
3. I need to be able to store the JWT so I can add them in the request header and I am thinking to store in cookie. Doesn't this give it the problem that cookie-based authentication have regarding CSRF?

Answer (score 0):

JWT Tokes are for webservice/Rest API calls.

For MVC pages you use Cookies, typically done via ASP.NET Core Identity.

You can also use JWT from Controllers, i.e. if you call a remote api. In this case you build your request via `HttpClient` and `SetBearerToken`, like this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoteCall()
{
    string accessToken = ...;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
        string content = await client.GetStringAsync("https://example.com/api/resource");

        return Content(content);
    }
}
```